# Creating a web service in C#

Tags: c#, iphone, web-services

I have sybase stored procedures that I have written which we use in our c# application and all is working well.  Now I am trying to use an IPAD and be able to call those stored procedures.  From what I understand I will need to build a webservice and expose those stored procedures.  I have become very familiar with IPHONE ( developed an app).  I learned how to call a web service from an IPHONE by posting some questions here and getting some tutorials.
I need to know how to build a web service in c# or if mac has an equivalent then so be it.  Are there documentation on how to build a web service around a stored procedure or even a sql?  I gladly read any books or documentations but I can't find any that is worth while.

Thanks
Saro

Comment: It's very easy to build a Web service in C sharp. just do a google search. the hard part will be the comunication between iphone and web service, I sugest you use JSON instead of XML. IF you use XML parsing's gonna be hard from the iphone to the web service

Comment: You got me very interested in JSON.  Any books or URL's you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definately recommend looking at WCF based web services rather than the old asmx web services. If you use WCF creating a service communicating in json is as easy as doing proper attribute decoration. What you need to look for is the `WebHttpBinding` and a

```
     [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

decorator on your methods. You can also use uri matching to get parameters etc.

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/lookup/{username}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Model.UserIdentifierResponse LookupUser(string username);
```

(Here the `{username}` is matched with the input parameter.)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Even if it is pretty old (but still valid), [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/myservice.aspx) is a short introduction into .net/C#-WebServices.
Basically WebServices are easy in .net, becasue the framework does most of the work for you.

Comment: Thanks.  Does mac have something similar?